# Making a Track Bar to change the Opacity of Form 1

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I'm a beginner at C# coding

I am trying to make a Track Bar that will change the opacity of the form using If statements.

```
       private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (trackBar1.Value == 1)
        {
            this.Opacity = (10);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 2)
        {
            this.Opacity = (20);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 3)
        {
            this.Opacity = (30);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 4)
        {
            this.Opacity = (40);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 5)
        {
            this.Opacity = (50);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 6)
        {
            this.Opacity = (60);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 7)
        {
            this.Opacity = (70);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 8)
        {
            this.Opacity = (80);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 9)
        {
            this.Opacity = (90);
        }
        if (trackBar1.Value == 10)
        {
            this.Opacity = (100);
        }
    }
```

But for some reason, My form opacity doesn't change. What does seem to be the problem?

Comment: [Opacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) is a double property between 0 and 1.If you try to set it to larger value, it will set to 1.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue, but why don't you replace all the `if`s with `this.Opactiy = 10 * trackBar1.Value`

Comment: Thanks! I now solved my problem

Comment: You need to set it `this.Opacity = trackBar1.Value * 0.1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the valid range for [`Opacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.110).aspx) property is a double value between 0 and 1. If you try to set it to a value larger than 1, it will set to 1, and if you try to set it to a value smaller than 0, it will set to 0. Here is the validation in [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,fd4314c70a25d203) of the property:

```
if (value > 1.0) {
    value = 1.0f;
}
else if (value < 0.0) {
    value = 0.0f;
}
```

To set the opacity of the form to 70% for example, you can set `Opacity` to `0.7`.

In your code, you need to set the opacity using:

```
this.Opacity = trackBar1.Value * 0.1;
```